# Transform a frame to be as if it was taken from above using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-rotation

I am working on a project for estimating a UAV (quadcopter) location using optical-flow technique. I currently have a code that is using [farneback](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) algorithm from OpenCV. The current code is working fine when the camera is always pointing to the ground.

Now, I want to add support to the case when the camera is not pointing straight down - meaning that the quadcopter now has a pitch / roll / yaw (Euler angles). The quadcopters  Euler angles are known and I am searching for a method to compute and apply the transformation needed based on the known current Euler angles. So that the result image will be as if it was taken from above (see image below).

I found methods that calculates the transformation when having 2 sets (source and destination) of 4 corners via `findHomography` or `getPerspectiveTransform` functions from OpenCV. But I couldn't find any methods that can do it with knowing only Euler angle (because I don't know the destination image corenrs).

So my question is what method can I use and how in order to transform a frame to be as if it was taken from above using only Euler angles and camera height from ground if necessary?

In order to demonstrate what I need:

[image]

The relevant part of my current code is below:

```
for(;;)
{
    Mat m, disp, warp;
    vector<Point2f> corners;
    // take out frame- still distorted
    cap >> origFrame;
    // undistort the frame using the calibration parameters
    cv::undistort(origFrame, undistortFrame, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, noArray());
    // lower the process effort by transforming the picture to gray
    cvtColor(undistortFrame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    if( !prevgray.empty() )
    {
        // calculate flow
        calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, gray, uflow, 0.5, 3/*def 3 */, 10/* def 15*/, 3, 3, 1.2 /* def 1.2*/, 0);
        uflow.copyTo(flow);

        // get average
        calcAvgOpticalFlow(flow, 16, corners);

        // calculate range of view - 2*tan(fov/2)*distance
        rovX = 2*0.44523*distanceSonar*100;     // 2 * tan(48/2) * dist(cm)
        rovY = 2*0.32492*distanceSonar*100;     // 2 * tan(36/2) * dist(cm)

        // calculate final x, y location
        location[0] += (currLocation.x/WIDTH_RES)*rovX;
        location[1] += (currLocation.y/HEIGHT_RES)*rovY;
    }
    //break conditions
    if(waitKey(1)>=0)
        break;
    if(end_run)
        break;
    std::swap(prevgray, gray);
}
```

### UPDATE:

**After successfully adding the rotation, I still need my image to be centered** (and not to go outside of the frame window as shown below). I guess I need some kind of translation. **I want the center of the source image to be at the center of the destination image.** How can I add this as well?

The rotation function that works:

```
void rotateFrame(const Mat &input, Mat &output, Mat &A , double roll, double pitch, double yaw){
    Mat Rx = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
              1,          0,           0,
              0, cos(roll), -sin(roll),
              0, sin(roll),  cos(roll));
    Mat Ry = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
              cos(pitch), 0, sin(pitch),
              0, 1,          0,
              -sin(pitch), 0,  cos(pitch));
    Mat Rz = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<
              cos(yaw), -sin(yaw), 0,
              sin(yaw),  cos(yaw), 0,
              0,          0,           1);

    Mat R = Rx*Ry*Rz;
    Mat trans = A*R*A.inv();

    warpPerspective(input, output, trans, input.size());
}
```

When I run it with `rotateFrame(origFrame, processedFrame, cameraMatrix, 0, 0, 0);` I get image as expected:

[image]

But when I run it with 10 degrees in roll `rotateFrame(origFrame, processedFrame, cameraMatrix, 20*(M_PI/180), 0, 0);`. The image is getting out of the frame window:

[image]

Comment: "_FindHomography or getPerspectiveTransform functions from OpenCV. But none that were doing it without knowing the corners positions but with known angles_" Are you sure they don't work with corners positions? Because I do my transformation using four corners

Comment: it wasn't clear enough, i've edited my post. I meant that I don't know the destination corners but I **do** know the Euler angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to a conclusion that I had to use the 4x4 Homography matrix in order to be able to get what I wanted. In order to find the right homography matrix we need:

1. 3D Rotation matrix `R`.
2. Camera calibration intrinsic matrix `A1` and its inverted matrix `A2`.
3. Translation matrix `T`.

We can compose the 3D rotation matrix `R` by multiplying the rotation matrices around axes X,Y,Z:

```
Mat R = RZ * RY * RX
```

In order to apply the transformation on the image and keep it centered we need to add translation given by a 4x4 matrix, where `dx=0; dy=0; dz=1` :

```
Mat T = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
         1, 0, 0, dx,
         0, 1, 0, dy,
         0, 0, 1, dz,
         0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Given all these matrices we can compose our homography matrix `H`:

```
Mat H = A2 * (T * (R * A1))
```

With this homography matrix we can then use `warpPerspective` function from OpenCV to apply the transformation.

```
warpPerspective(input, output, H, input.size(), INTER_LANCZOS4);
```

For conclusion and completeness of this solution here is the full code:

```
void rotateImage(const Mat &input, UMat &output, double roll, double pitch, double yaw,
                 double dx, double dy, double dz, double f, double cx, double cy)
  {
    // Camera Calibration Intrinsics Matrix
    Mat A2 = (Mat_<double>(3,4) <<
              f, 0, cx, 0,
              0, f, cy, 0,
              0, 0, 1,  0);
    // Inverted Camera Calibration Intrinsics Matrix
    Mat A1 = (Mat_<double>(4,3) <<
              1/f, 0,   -cx/f,
              0,   1/f, -cy/f,
              0,   0,   0,
              0,   0,   1);
    // Rotation matrices around the X, Y, and Z axis
    Mat RX = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
              1, 0,         0,          0,
              0, cos(roll), -sin(roll), 0,
              0, sin(roll), cos(roll),  0,
              0, 0,         0,          1);
    Mat RY = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
              cos(pitch),  0, sin(pitch), 0,
              0,           1, 0,          0,
              -sin(pitch), 0, cos(pitch), 0,
              0,           0, 0,          1);
    Mat RZ = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
              cos(yaw), -sin(yaw), 0, 0,
              sin(yaw),  cos(yaw), 0, 0,
              0,          0,       1, 0,
              0,          0,       0, 1);
    // Translation matrix
    Mat T = (Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
             1, 0, 0, dx,
             0, 1, 0, dy,
             0, 0, 1, dz,
             0, 0, 0, 1);
    // Compose rotation matrix with (RX, RY, RZ)
    Mat R = RZ * RY * RX;
    // Final transformation matrix
    Mat H = A2 * (T * (R * A1));
    // Apply matrix transformation
    warpPerspective(input, output, H, input.size(), INTER_LANCZOS4);
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: I stumbled across your solution doing similar things, did you come up with a way to solve the cropping issue?

Comment: @DeusExMachina25 what do you mean by cropping issue? This solution above is the most updated solution I've used. Maybe there are other better / simpler ways to do this but this one above did the job as described in the question.

Comment: I ended up developing a different solution but used yours to learn. I was referring to the fact that the image was place in a box that wasn't large enough, as imaged in your post. Part of the image gets clipped by the bounding box.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a [calibration intrinsics matrix A](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) (3x3), and there is no translation between camara poses, all you need to find homography H (3x3) is to [construct rotation matrix R (3x3) from euler angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) and apply the following formula:

```
H = A * R * A.inv()
```

Where .inv() is matrix invertion.

**UPDATED:**

If you want to center the image, you should just add translation this way:
(this is finding the warped position of the center and translation of this point back to the center)

```
|dx|       | 320 / 2 |
|dy| = H * | 240 / 2 |
|1 |       | 1       |

    | 1 0 (320/2-dx) | 
W = | 0 1 (240/2-dy) | * H
    | 0 0 1          |
```

W is your final transformation.

Comment: Thanks! can you explain more about how to create the calibration intrinsic matrix? Do I need to add also a translation? (and not only rotation).

Comment: @A.Sarid intrinsics matrix is constructed from intrinsics: focal lengths, skew, and principal point. You need to calibrate your camera to get these values. You can find more information [there](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html). Regarding second question - if you want to have view of the plane from the same point, but from different angle, you don't need to add translation.

Comment: I've updated my post - please take a look. The image is getting out of the frame, even in small angle. Are you sure I don't need any translation?

Comment: Firstly, you have an error in rotation matrix construction. Plase refer to string (48) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html). Secondly, what is your A matrix? How did you get it?

Comment: Does it matter? The final `R` is what matters, for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) they use different convention. Second, I have the intrinsic matrix from calibration I did for this camera before.

Comment: @A.Sarid Carefully look at the signs before sin(). Are you sure, your calibration matrix is correct? Have you checked it somehow?

Comment: @A.Sarid On the second image you have scaling. A list of paper is ~1.5 times bigger. So, I think, your calibration matrix is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111878/discussion-between-a-sarid-and-aleksey-petrov).

Comment: I still need the translation, I want the image to be centered. Please see my update above.

Comment: I've already answered you in the chat how to translate the image. In your function rotateFrame you should change trans matrix just before warping this way: trans = [1, 0, dx, 
0, 1, dy, 
0, 0, 1 ] * trans

Comment: Yes, thanks, but how can I know the values of dx, dy in order to make my image always centered?

Answer (score 0):

This how I do it in [**Eigen**](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and using 4 corners:

```
// Desired four corners
std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f> Normalized_Reference_Pattern = { Eigen::Vector2f(0, 0), Eigen::Vector2f(0, 2), Eigen::Vector2f(2, 0), Eigen::Vector2f(2, 2) }; 

// Current four points
std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f> CurrentCentroids = { /* Whatever four corners you want, but relative sueqnece to above */ };

// Transform for current to desired
auto Master_Transform = get_perspective_transform(CurrentCentroids, Normalized_Reference_Pattern);

// abilitu to use the same tranformation for other points (other than the corners) in the image
Eigen::Vector2f Master_Transform_Centroid = Master_Transform * Eigen::Vector2f(currentX, currentY);
```

And here is my black box:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f get_perspective_transform(const std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f>& points_from,const std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f>& points_to)
{
    cv::Mat transform_cv = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(
        convert::to_cv(points_from), 
        convert::to_cv(points_to));

    Eigen::Matrix3f transform_eigen;
    cv::cv2eigen(transform_cv, transform_eigen);
    return transform_eigen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! But still, I can't understand how do I know the desired 4 corners if I have only the Euler angles of the quadcopter.

Comment: @A. How do you store the image in your system? Can't you just take the corner points `[0,0]`, `[0, WidthSize-1]`, `[Height-1, 0]` and `[Height-1, Width-1]` ?

Comment: Yes, but that is my source, the destination corners has to be some kind of trapeze if I understand it right.

Comment: You choose the desired corners, and it could be any. In my example, I choose the new "image" to be 2x2; Where `Eigen::Vector2f(0, 0), Eigen::Vector2f(0, 2), Eigen::Vector2f(2, 0), Eigen::Vector2f(2, 2)` are my "destination" corners, then my current ROI's points will be transofrmed to that. In your case, your ROI is the whole image

Comment: Ok. So how does the transformation know the angle of the image? If for example my camera was 30 degrees from ground. I guess that there has to be some use of rotation matrix or something similar that uses the euler angles.

Comment: I don't know about that.. (maybe because I didn't need angles). I just tell my system: _see these four corners_ ... _Good_ .. _Now Transfer them to these "Virtual" Four corners_. Result: 2d "virtual" image, which is flat "angle zero from the camera"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111450/discussion-between-a-sarid-and-firststep).