# OpenCV + Python - how to compensate the egomotion of the camera?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, affinetransform, opticalflow

Exactly, how is the egomotion of a moving camera is compensate (to segment out the independently moving object relative to the camera)? From my reading it has something to do with get some interesting points from the video, track it with optical flow, get the affine matrix and then, warp it. But I can't really relate on how this things manage to compensate the egomotion.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117939/transform-a-frame-to-be-as-if-it-was-taken-from-above-using-opencv)  help? Let me know if this is what you meant. I can explain more if needed.

Comment: @A.Sarid I am afraid it is not necessarily what I meant. As for my case, let say the video camera is moving, and there is other object that is also moving independently (let say a car). I want to be able to segment out the car only. I am as for right now, referring to this [work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkAOwEBRBP8) but still can't really understand what is being done.